# Why doesn't my JComboBox paint over my drawings?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a simple drawing pad in Java and I have a few tools the user can work with: pen and eraser. But the JComboBox used to select the tool doesn't appear, even though it's added. I have heard that a custom paint will cover up any JComponents. If that is true how can I make the JComboBox always be on top?

Picture of the window:

[image: picture of bugged window]

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class DrawFrame extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Image dbi;
    private Graphics dbg;

    ArrayList<Integer> px = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> py = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int mx;
    int my;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    JComboBox tool = new JComboBox();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DrawFrame() {

        setSize(480, 480);
        setTitle("ScratchPad _14");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setOpacity(1);

        tool.addItem("Pen");
        tool.addItem("Eraser");

        tool.setEnabled(true);

        add(tool);

        setVisible(true);

        addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    /*@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DrawFrame df = new DrawFrame();
        Thread t = new Thread(df);

        t.start();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        dbi = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbi.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbi, 0, 0, null);

    }

    private void draw(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < px.size(); i++) {

            g.fillOval(px.get(i), py.get(i), 3, 3);

        }

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("(" + mx + ", " + my + ")", mx + 10, my - 5);

        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while(true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x = m.getX();
        int y = m.getY();

        mx = x;
        my = y;

        px.add(x);
        py.add(y);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x = m.getX();
        int y = m.getY();

        mx = x;
        my = y;

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you called `super.paint`, which paints the child components, amongst other things

```
super.paint(g);
```

Then you filled the entire frame with the background color using...

```
g.setColor(getBackground());
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Erasing that was painted before it...

You should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame`, apart from the fact you'd be painting under the frame decorations and it's not double buffered, these containers are actually made up of a number compound components which produce the final output.

Instead, create a custom component extending from, something like `JPanel`, and override its `paintComponent` method.  Place your custom painting here.

Add the combo box and custom paint panel to the frame separately

Also, don't call anything from any paint method that may generate a repaint event (like calling `repaint`), this will set up a infinite loop which will quickly consume your CPU

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Removing `super.paint(g)` doesn't do anything visible. And the frame IS double buffered.

Comment: Never stop calling super.paint, that's not the problem. The problem is, `super.paint`, paints the child components, but then you paint over them and yes, you've double buffered the frame, but guess what, JComponent's are double buffered default, saving you from having to do this yourself. A JFrame consists of a JRootPane, JLayeredPane, content pane and glass pane, and you've just painted over the lot. If you want to fix the problem, separate your custom painting and components

Comment: In eclipse, not manually double buffering causes the drawing to blink with too many items on the screen.

Comment: @galennare This has nothing to do with eclipse. This is the fact the top level containers aren't double buffered. Instead, use something like a JPanel and override its paintComponent method. All components extending from JComponent are double buffered by default

Comment: what is "double buffered" which is being discussed here?

Comment: @MohamedIqzas Double buffering is a technique by which graphics is painted first to a backing buffer before that is drawn to the screen, it reduces the number of physical paint operations and flickering as the graphics is updated. It's also more efficient, as blit'ing a bitmap to the screen is faster than drawing individual primitives

Answer (score 0):

In general, one should usually *not* override the paint method of JFrame. Instead, you should extend JPanel, and paint in an overridden `paintComponent` method.

```
class PaintPanel extends JPanel
{
    public PaintPanel()
    {
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        // Paint what you have been painting 
        // in your "draw" method ...
        ...
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Usually, the `super.paintComponent(g)` call should be the FIRST call of such an overridden method, but since you want to draw the ComboBox above everything that you paint on your own, it has to be the last.

Additional issues:

- What is that Thread for?
- Why are you doing manual double buffering?
- IF you want manual double buffering, you should not re-create the image in each paint call

SLIGHTLY cleaned up, not "nice" yet, but ... in a way that still resembles the original program, at least:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class DrawFrame extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ArrayList<Integer> px = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> py = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int mx;
    int my;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    JComboBox tool = new JComboBox();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DrawFrame() {

        setSize(480, 480);
        setTitle("ScratchPad _14");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setOpacity(1);

        tool.addItem("Pen");
        tool.addItem("Eraser");

        tool.setEnabled(true);

        JPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        paintPanel.add(tool);
        add(paintPanel);

        setVisible(true);

        paintPanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawFrame df = new DrawFrame();
    }

    class PaintPanel extends JPanel
    {
        public PaintPanel()
        {
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override 
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
        {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int i = 0; i < px.size(); i++) {
                g.fillOval(px.get(i), py.get(i), 3, 3);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawString("(" + mx + ", " + my + ")", mx + 10, my - 5);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {
        int x = m.getX();
        int y = m.getY();

        mx = x;
        my = y;

        px.add(x);
        py.add(y);

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {
        int x = m.getX();
        int y = m.getY();

        mx = x;
        my = y;

    }

}
```

Comment: The thread and double buffering prevents the frame from allowing the custom painted items on the screen from blinking in between frames.

Comment: Does the cleaned up code cause flicker for you? Swing Components are by default double buffered, but overriding `paint` of a JFrame destroys everything, of course....

Comment: Since I did exactly that, this was probably meant to be @Galen Nare (the original poster)

Comment: @GalenNare Swing employees a passive painting algorithm, generally this means, it will repaint what and when it thinks something needs to be painted. Instead of trying to use a Thread or calling repaint from within the paint method, you could simply call repaint within the mouse event methods. Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The drawing should not call repaint. I have done that in mouseDragged with a delay of 50 ms.
Then, double buffering is default, so you do not collect all changes first in an image.
Erasing is done for one too.

So the code becomes:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < px.size(); i++) {
        g.fillOval(px.get(i), py.get(i), 3, 3);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawString("(" + mx + ", " + my + ")", mx + 10, my - 5);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {
    ...
    repaint(50L);
}
```

Normally one introduces a JPanel for painting, which has a `paintComponent` to override.

Comment: Not calling repaint makes it skip frames.

Comment: @GalenNare then add a repaint in mouseMoved too. The idea is that if there is no change to display, do not call repaint. Please check in the task manager the CPU usage in both cases.